# After uploading image to aws s3, and the page reloads image is not found, but next time yes

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, sharp

I am uploading images to s3 on the users edit profile page,
it works, but after the image is saved in s3, and the page reloads after saving the changes.

The image is not found, however, if i refresh the page it is, there...

Any ideas what can be the issue?

This appnes in the controller:

```
exports.resize = async (req, res, next) => {
  // check if there is no new file to resize
  if (!req.file) {
    next(); // skip to the next middlewaree
    return;
  }
  const extension = req.file.mimetype.split('/')[1]
  req.body.photo = `${uuid.v4()}.${extension}`

  let readyimg
  const imageAws = await sharp(req.file.buffer)
    .resize(800, 800)
    .toBuffer()
    .then( data => {
      readyimg = data
    })

  AWS.config.update({
    secretAccessKey: process.env.SECRETACCESSKEY,
    accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESSKEYID,
    region: 'us-east-1'
  })

  const s3 = new AWS.S3()

  const params = {
    Bucket: 'jamsession-images',
    Key: req.body.photo,
    Body: readyimg
  };

  await s3.upload(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% error in callback');
      console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('****************** success');
    console.log(data);
  });

  next()
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it fixed itself... i guess aws bucket needs to get a couple of request before being usable?